# For loop cannot convert from int to double[]

Tags: java

For reading a lot of lines I've made a loop to start reading from line 0
all the way to line 61166. However if I try to compile this file all I get is that I cannot convert from `int` to `double[]` even though the variables are not integers. What have I done wrong? TBH I am a really beginner if it's about java. This is for a school exercise

```
int m = 61166;                                               
int[] l = new int[m];                                         
double[] p = new double[m] ;                                    
double[] q = new double[m];                                    

for (p = 0; p < m ; p++);
```

Comment: You've declared `p` as a `double[]`, but are trying to set its value to `0`.  What exactly is this loop attempting to do?

Comment: your code is incomplete. Would you provide the entire?

Comment: What we are trying to get this loop to do, is if we get input the loop will read a text file from line 0 to line 61166 till it finds a match with the input (it's like a coordinate text file).

Comment: Use a different variable as the loop index.  `for (int index = 0; index < m; index++ ) { .... }`.  And lose the semicolon at the end of the `for` line.  As a general rule, single-letter variable names tend to be a bad idea.  Use variable names that clearly indicate what the variable is actually for.

Comment: I will try to illustrate the problem. We have gotten ourselves a text file with coordinates of the boundaries of zip codes. We have to make a java program which matches the input coordinates to a number which later on in the text file corresponds to a province and a city. And as an output you will get something like "input coordinates are in this province and this city.

Comment: @TomvanMaasdam: That's a pretty broad description of what these few lines of code are intending to accomplish.  Nevertheless, the reason for the error is because you can't assign an `int` value to a `double[]` variable.

Comment: As others have mentioned your variable in the for loop has previously been used and therefore assigning a int to it won't work.  Secondly your for loop has no body, while syntactically it is correct it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to use an array as your loop index/incrementer. In theory, you could do something like this:

```
    int m = 61166;                                               
    int[] l = new int[m];                                         
    double[] p = new double[m] ;                                    
    double[] q = new double[m];                                    

    for (p[0] = 0; p[0] < m ; p[0]++);
```

But I don't think that will make your program run the way you want it too. I think you might want to do something like this:

```
    int m = 61166;                                               
    int[] l = new int[m];                                         
    double[] p = new double[m] ;                                    
    double[] q = new double[m];                                    

    for (int index = 0; index < m ; index++){
        //perform operations on your loop
        p[index] = //something
        q[index] = //etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `p` like an `int` value whereas it is of type `double[]`.
Use the following code instead:
`for (int pp = 0; pp < m; pp++)`

Comment: so how could i be able to change it's type to just double and not double []? because i could change the for p = 0 to p = 0.0 to make it a double but than i still get the error cannot convert from double to double []

Comment: I do not know your purpose, if you attempt to have a variable of type double as the counter of your loop, you should write: *double a = 0.0*. but I highly recommend you use `int` values as the counter of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple you declared `p` as an array of `double`:

```
double[] p = new double[m];
```

Then you try to set it's value to `0` (`p = 0;`) which of course won't work since 0 has `int` as a type (that's what the compiler normally assumes for numbers unless explicitly told otherwise).

It's like being told: *create an empty list that can hold 61166 double values. Now set the value of the list to 0*. You'd probably be confused as well.